# excel - find multiple duplicated values with different arrangement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to make my life easier and write a script that searches and highlights duplicated value in Excel.

I have, as example, 2 Rows with complex values. First Row is not so important cause it's only a name, but the second is important and here I can't figure it out how to search for duplicates. One big thing is that the vale is the same, but it can be sometimes differently written.

Can you please help me, while i still search it manually and after 2 hours I lost my sight and mind :)

Comment: I guess they are not duplicates though - because the values you are identifying are not *exactly* the same. They are 'look-alikes'. You need to edit your question about what rules you are using to detect a match.

Comment: please also put an extract of your file instead of a picture

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Comment: Hi Ralph, thanks for your welcome. I know that this isn't "please write me a code" Site, but I really don't know how to start, or better to say, with what should I start. I know it should youse Search function, but i don't know how can I Find duplicates that are not exactly the same...that's why I need your help...with Examples or with just a discription how to do it.
TNX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could exploit:

- `SortedList` object, to create a code Key which is independent of "values" occurrence order in each column "Code" cells
- `Dictionary` object, to collect all "persons" corresponding to the same code Key

as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim codeKey As Variant, persons As Variant
    Dim codesRng As Range

    Set codesRng = Range("C3", Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp)) '<--| set the range with all codes

    Normalize codesRng '<--| rewrite codes with only one delimiter

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '<--| instantiate a 'Dictionary' object
        For iRow = 1 To codesRng.Rows.count '<--| loop through 'codesRng' cells
            codeKey = GetKey(codesRng(iRow, 1)) '<--| get its "Key"
            .item(codeKey) = .item(codeKey) & codesRng(iRow, 1).Offset(, -2) & "|" '<--| update current 'codeKey' dictionary item with  the corresponding "person"
        Next

        For Each codeKey In .Keys '<--| loop through dictionary keys
            persons = Split(Left(.item(codeKey), Len(.item(codeKey)) - 1), "|") '<--| get current key array of "persons"
            If UBound(persons) > 0 Then Debug.Print Join(persons, ",") '<--| print them if more than one person
        Next
    End With '<--| release 'Dictionary' object
End Sub

Sub Normalize(rng As Range)
    With rng
        .Replace " ", "", xlPart
        .Replace "+-", "+", xlPart
        .Replace "(", "", xlPart
        .Replace ")", "", xlPart
        .Replace "/", "+", xlPart
        .Replace "+Ax", "Ax", xlPart
        .Replace "+", "|", xlPart
    End With
End Sub

Function GetKey(strng As String) As Variant
    Dim elements As Variant
    Dim j As Long

    elements = Split(strng, "|") '<--| get an array of values out of those found delimited by a pipe ("|") in the string

    With CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList") '<--| instantiate a 'SortedList' object
        For j = 0 To UBound(elements) '<--| loop through array values
            .item(CStr(elements(j))) = "" '<--| add them to 'SortedList' object
        Next

        For j = 0 To .count - 1 '<--| iterate through 'SortedList' object elements
            elements(j) = .GetKey(j) '<--| write back array values in sorted order
        Next
    End With '<--| release 'SortedList' object

    GetKey = Join(elements, "|") '<--| return the "Key" as a string obtained from the passed one sorted values
End Function
```

Comment: @159_v6, did you get through it?

Comment: Yes and no :)
I have tried it other way, but I'm getting a new problem now.
Excell sorted all out, but how can I "see" an Error when someone types it wrong, or when the possitions are switched

ex.   
+302/402/6UB+235/3R    .....    +402/302/6UB+235/3R

Comment: Yes, just few thing, while they gave me better results 
        .Replace " ", "", xlPart
        .Replace "+-", "-", xlPart
        .Replace "(", "", xlPart
        .Replace ")", "", xlPart

Comment: fine. so you may want to accept my answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you!

Comment: can you help me with sorting the thing out? have you few Examples in your mind

Comment: I don't get what do you need help for?

Comment: can you please see the example under this article? it is marked in yellow

Comment: my code already recognizes the two codes marked in yellow as the same code, thus fixing the error

Comment: Yeah, you're right! I didn't see that it shows all the infos in Immediate_Window

Comment: @ user3598756 - can you print the result into log or somewhere else so that it can be saved as a file?

Answer (score 0):

a sample code that might help to start with

```
Sub same()

    Dim a$(), i%, i1%, i2%, j%, r$, s As Boolean, w$, k, t$, dict As Object, c$
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    i = 1
    While Cells(i, 3) <> ""
        ' first split string into multiple strings
        j = 0
        r = Cells(i, 3)
        For i1 = 1 To Len(r)
            c = Mid(r, i1, 1)
            Select Case c
            Case "+", "-", "/", "(", ")"
                s = True
            Case Else
                w = w & c
            End Select
            If s = True Or i1 = Len(r) Then
                If w <> "" Then
                    j = j + 1
                    ReDim Preserve a(j)
                    a(j) = w
                    w = ""
                    s = False
                End If
            End If
        Next i1
        ' sort the strings in ascending order
        k = 0
        For i1 = 1 To j - 1
            k = i1
            For i2 = i1 + 1 To j
                If a(i2) < a(k) Then k = i2
            Next i2
            t = a(i1): a(i1) = a(k): a(k) = t
        Next i1
        ' detect if doublons using a dictionary
        k = Join(a, "-")
        If dict.exists(k) Then 'doublon detected
            Cells(i, 4) = dict.Item(k)
            Cells(dict.Item(k), 4) = Cells(dict.Item(k), 4) & " " & i
        Else
            dict.Add k, i
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: TNX, I'll try it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Example #user3598756
I have added this separate Module and I can see duplicates in colors which is extremely helpful

```
Sub Find_Duplicate_Entry()
Dim cel As Variant
Dim myrng As Range
Dim clr As Long
Set myrng = Range("O4:O" & Range("O65536").End(xlUp).Row)
myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
clr = 3
For Each cel In myrng
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cel) > 1 Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("O2:O" & cel.Row), cel) = 1 Then
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
            clr = clr + 1
        Else
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = myrng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, myrng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Now the only problem left is when the Codes have switched positions.

Example:

> (**A302x/A402x**/A6U8x)+(A235x/A3ARx)
>
> (**A402x/A302x**/A6U8x)+(A235x/A3ARx)

Excel sees no duplicates, but for my case, it's an Error